# Slow Nginx + PHP-FPM during High Traffic on Magento Enterprise

Tags: magento, nginx

We are using Nginx with PHP-FPM for Magento Enterprise Edition 1.12

Everything works fine but when we get visitors over 150 the speed drops. During this time we have noticed that CPU utilization is 10% with over 40% free mem.

Server Configuration:

```
CPU 2 x Intel Xeon E5-2680 2.7 GHz 8 Cores 16 Threads 8 GT/s (w H/T) 
RAM 8GB x 8 = 64 GB Total 
NIC 1G connected to Firewall
NIC 1G connected to DB server running percona MySQL
```

Configuration: nginx.conf

```
user nginx;
worker_processes 32;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
worker_connections  1024;
# multi_accept on;
}

http {
include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile          on;
tcp_nopush        on;
tcp_nodelay       off;
autoindex         off;
keepalive_timeout 10;

## detect https
map $scheme $fastcgi_https {
    default off;
    https on;
}
# Store FastCGI Cached (microcaching) of PHP pages in our tmpfs ramdisk
fastcgi_cache_path /tmpfs/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=mage:5m max_size=1g inactive=1h;
open_file_cache max=10000 inactive=30m;
open_file_cache_valid 10m;
open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
open_file_cache_errors on;
proxy_read_timeout 10;

upstream phpfpm {
    server localhost:9000;
}

gzip on;
gzip_http_version 1.0;
gzip_comp_level 2;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_min_length  1100;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml
application/xml+rss text/javascript;
# Some version of IE 6 don't handle compression well on some mime-types, so just disable for them
gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6].(?!.*SV1)";
# Set a vary header so downstream proxies don't send cached gzipped content to IE6
gzip_vary on;

# Load config files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

# Health-check server
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    charset      utf-8;
    access_log off;
    location / {
        root   share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;

    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;
    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   share/nginx/html;
    }

    }
```

}

Configurtation PHP-FPM.conf

```
[global]
pid = /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.pid
error_log = /var/log/php-fpm/error.log
[www]
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
listen.backlog = 65536
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
user = nginx
group = nginx
request_terminate_timeout = 600
pm = static
pm.max_children = 846
#pm.start_servers = 200
#pm.min_spare_servers = 200
#pm.max_spare_servers = 200
pm.max_requests = 10000
slowlog = /var/log/php-fpm/www-slow.log
```

configuation fastcgi.conf

```
#fastcgi_set_header "Set-Cookie";
#if ($http_cookie != "X-Store=1" ) {
#  add_header Set-Cookie "X-Store=1; path=/";
#}

## Catch 404s that try_files miss
if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }

## Blacklist media location from fcgi
if ($uri !~ "^/(media|skin|js)/") {
fastcgi_pass phpfpm;
}

## Tell the upstream who is making the request
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_redirect off;

# Ensure PHP knows when we use HTTPS
fastcgi_param  HTTPS           $fastcgi_https;

## Fcgi Settings
include                        fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_connect_timeout        60;
fastcgi_send_timeout           60;
fastcgi_read_timeout           300;
fastcgi_buffer_size            4k;
fastcgi_buffers 512            4k;
fastcgi_busy_buffers_size      8k;
fastcgi_temp_file_write_size   256k;
fastcgi_intercept_errors       off;
fastcgi_index  index.php;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME     $fastcgi_script_name;
# nginx will buffer objects to disk that are too large for the buffers above
fastcgi_temp_path              /tmpfs/nginx/tmp 1 2;
#fastcgi_keep_conn              on; # NGINX 1.1.14
expires                        off; ## Do not cache dynamic content
```

Top

```
top - 13:24:45 up  5:58,  1 user,  load average: 0.88, 0.70, 0.71
Tasks: 1465 total,   3 running, 1462 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  4.1%us,  0.1%sy,  0.0%ni, 95.8%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  65942708k total, 38795452k used, 27147256k free,   213844k buffers
Swap:  8388600k total,        0k used,  8388600k free,  1263300k cached

PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
3300 nginx     20   0 1404m 169m 127m S 28.3  0.3   0:30.33 php-fpm
4165 nginx     20   0 1401m 156m 117m S 26.0  0.2   0:30.17 php-fpm
4072 nginx     20   0 1410m 163m 118m S 22.7  0.3   0:27.75 php-fpm
3710 nginx     20   0 1402m 163m 123m R 12.8  0.3   0:32.39 php-fpm
3578 nginx     20   0 1401m 157m 118m S 11.9  0.2   0:27.39 php-fpm
```

We are using magento enterprise and using Full Page Cache. APC is also installed and active.

Problem: Get extremely slow during high traffic.

Steve

Comment: CPU usage looks like more than 10%. Magento isn't light software, I'm not surprised the CPU is struggling to process the entire system each and every PHP request. Have you profiled the application with XDebug to see which parts take the most time/memory? Also, I'd use `htop` instead of `top`.

Comment: I am working to install XDebug. So you don't see anything wrong with Nginx conf.?

Comment: We had 70 active visitors on the website. When we stress test the machine with 250 visitors the CPU spikes to 12%.

Comment: Are you sure this machine is the problem? Usually the database node is the first to start slowing from the excessive queries thrown at it. Assuming 150 users a second x 15 queries each page = 2,250 queries a second. If the MySQL database isn't slowing, see if the 1GB network is saturated.

Comment: At any rate, you need better logging setup so that the system can tell *you* what the problem is. Check out the MySQL tunning scripts online, enable the MySQL slow query log, install XDebug on your **local** development machine (since it slows things down) and see what parts of the application are the slowest or send the most queries. Check your nginx and PHP-FPM logs.

Comment: @user1538621 what software are you using to stress test the machine?

Comment: I am using web performance and also using curl from shell. I have notice when I have more than 5 active processes, things started to slow down. There are no slow queries log in mysql. No errors in nginx or php-fpm.

Comment: Do you see anything in the php-fpm slow logs? Make sure you have that enabled, and you'll see stack trace dumps when a php-fpm process exceeds the slow threshold.
Also, what type of cache backend are you using and are you sure all caches are enabled?

Comment: When you view top processes does the 'res' memory keep growing? With magento, the RES memory is usually between 35M and 150M for each php-fpm process. Does the Value grow over time for each process?

Answer (score 0):

I answered this question pretty thoroughly here...

[NGINX-FPM configuration settings for magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359337/nginx-fpm-configuration-settings-for-magento/14360603#14360603)

In quick summary,

> What you are asking is something I think everyone struggles with using
>   nginx and php fpm... Squeezing more performance from it. I mean, we
>   could just use apache and php if we weren't trying to get the site
>   performance increase right? There are a lot answers, opinions, and
>   case base solutions... However, the problem is indeed Magento, rather than the configuration of the server. Magento is just too large and too heavy to any environment. Magento hosting is really tedious and unpleasant task.